# Unable to mount any filesystems

Tags: mount, nfs, cifs

Since today afternoon, I'm unable to access any of my filesystems. Whenever I try to open any of them I get the following error

[image]

So I would like to describe an issue which might have caused this.

I tried to install fingerprint driver for my laptop (DELL Inspiron 5501). I got carried away with many articles finally downloaded a package which literally checks for any available fingerprint drivers. In order to do that a file with `.AppImage` had to be run. In order to run that Fuse was needed. So I installed `fuse` and `libfuse2`. After that this message appears everytime I open a filesystem.

I tried installing `nfs-common` and `cifs-utils`. However during installing nfs-common the ouput was like this.

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  open-iscsi watchdog
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nfs-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/240 kB of archives.
After this operation, 901 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nfs-common.
(Reading database ... 222095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nfs-common_1%3a2.6.1-2ubuntu4.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nfs-common (1:2.6.1-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Setting up nfs-common (1:2.6.1-2ubuntu4.1) ...
auth-rpcgss-module.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
nfs-idmapd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
nfs-utils.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
proc-fs-nfsd.mount is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
rpc-gssd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
rpc-statd-notify.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
rpc-statd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
rpc-svcgssd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-2) ...
```

Please help me to find a solution!

And yes I removed fuse.

Comment: Can you remove fuse and reinstall fuse3? Or does the install command you show above hang and not finish? (Clarify this in your answer)

Comment: @vanadium `fuse3` is already installed, it says `fuse3 is already the newest version (3.11.0-1).
fuse3 set to manually installed.`

Comment: @vanadium also, The above install command finishes and does not hang, I can see `mount.nfs` and `mount.cifs` in `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to fix the issue without an installation medium,
check if `mount.ntfs`, `mount.ntfs-3g` and `mount.lowntfs-3g` are present in `/sbin` apart from `nfs-common` and `cifs-utils` using

```
ls -l /sbin/mount.ntfs
ls -l /sbin/mount.ntfs-3g
ls -l /sbin/mount.lowntfs-3g
```

If they are not present install them using

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Do a *reboot*(sometimes not necessary)

If it still **doesn't work**, download Ubuntu and create a bootable USB (refer [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview))

After booting into USB go to **Try Ubuntu** instead of Install Ubuntu and mount all the filesystems from there. Usually they will be automatically mounted. However, the files needed for mounting the partitions will be automatically created if they are not present.

That's it. Hope it helps!